# Calculate time between 2 events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I'm currently doing a beginners course in Javascript and am working on a very basic project which is essentially a reaction timer. The idea is that random shapes (squares or circles only) appear in random positions at random intervals and the user has to click on them.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var shape = document.getElementById("shape");

  function generateRandomShape() {
    console.log("TEST");
    var shapeType = ["50%", ""];
    var shapeColor = ["red", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "brown", "gray", "black", "blue"];

    shape.classList.remove("disappear");
    shape.style.backgroundColor = shapeColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapeColor.length)];
    shape.style.height = Math.random() * 300 + "px";
    shape.style.width = shape.style.height;
    shape.style.borderRadius = shapeType[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapeType.length)];
    shape.style.marginLeft = Math.random() * 700;
    shape.style.marginTop = Math.random() * 300;
  }

  shape.onclick = function() {
    var endTime = Date.now();
    var randomDelay = Math.random() * 3000;
    var startTime = endTime - randomDelay;
    var reaction = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;

    setTimeout(generateRandomShape, randomDelay);
    shape.className = "disappear";

    document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = endTime;
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = startTime;
    document.getElementById("reactionTime").innerHTML = reaction;
  }
  
  generateRandomShape();
});
```

```css
.disappear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
<p>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p>
<p>Your time is: <span id="reactionTime"></span> seconds</p>
<div id="shape"></div>
<div id="start"></div>
<div id="end"></div>
<div id="reactionTime"></div>
```

It all works OK except for the reaction timer and I just cannot work out how to get this to work. I'm creating the endTime variable upon clicking the shape but cannot get my head around the startTime variable. How do I store the time that the shape appeared? Clearly my attempt here doesn't work and I can easily see why, but I cannot figure out what I should be putting. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Your code**: there is no DOM element with id="end" and id="start", so your onclick function just fails there. This error must have shown in your debug console.

**Using common sense is enough to solve your problem:**

1. Store a start time value whenever your shape is created. A global variable is not enough if you want to have multiple shapes appearing at once. It depends on your preference, but a better approach is to store the time value as a DOM attribute then you can retrieve it from the shape when you click it.
2. When it is clicked, generate another time value, then get the difference between the two time values and print it on the screen.

I recommend to work on the core logic first then you can decorate your app easily. Here's my solution:

```
/* HTML:
<h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
<p>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p>
<p>Your time is: <span id="reactionTime">0</span> seconds</p>
<div id="shape">Click me!</div>
*/
var shape = document.getElementById("shape");
var reactionResult = document.getElementById("reactionTime");

function generateRandomShape() {
    // make the shape appear again
    shape.classList.remove("disappear");
    // store creation time as attribute "start-time"
    shape.setAttribute("start-time", new Date().toISOString());
    // decorate or change your shape style here ...
};

shape.onclick = function() {
    // make the shape disappear
    shape.className = "disappear";
    // retrieving creating time from attribute "start-time"
    var startTime = new Date(shape.getAttribute("start-time"));
    // calculate reaction time
    var reactionTime = new Date() - startTime;
    // displaying reaction time
    reactionResult.innerHTML = reactionTime / 1000;
    // creating next shape in random time
    var randomDelay = Math.random() * 3000;
    setTimeout(generateRandomShape, randomDelay);
};

generateRandomShape();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your generate shape and your shape event listener in the same scope.

In that same scope, create two variables to track the `showTime`, and `clickTime`... Set your `showTime` when your generate a random shape, set your click time inside your event listener, then populate the html.

```
var showTime,
    clickTime;

function generateShape() {
    showTime = Date.now();
    ...
}

...

shape.onClick = function() {
    clickTime = Date.now();
    document.getElementById('reactionTime').innerHTML = clickTime - showTime;
    ...
}
```